# Highlighting word excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA program that will allow me to mine through a set of Excel data and pull out relevant information which is then copied to another sheet.

I keep trying to make it so that the word that is being searched for is highlighted in yellow, however my program constantly throws "Compile error - expected array on Ubound".

```
Option Compare Text

Public Sub Textchecker()
'
' Textchecker
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
Dim Continue As Long
Dim findWhat As String
Dim LastLine As Long
Dim toCopy As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
Dim item As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sheetIndex As Long
Dim inclusion As String

sheetIndex = 2

Continue = vbYes
    Do While Continue = vbYes

        findWhat = CStr(InputBox("What word would you like to search for today?"))
        inclusion = CStr(InputBox("Do you have any inclusions? Separate words with commas"))
        LastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If findWhat = "" Then Exit Sub
        j = 1
    For item = 1 To LastLine
        If UBound(inclusion) >= 0 Then
            For Each cell In Range("BY1").Offset(item - 1, 0) Then
                For Each item In inclusion
                    If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 And InStr(cell.Text, inclusion) <> 0 Then
                        findWhat.Interior.Color = 6
                        toCopy = True
        Else
            For Each cell In Range("BY1").Offset(item - 1, 0) Then
                If InStr(cell.Text, findWhat) <> 0 Then
                    findWhat.Interior.Color = 6
                    toCopy = True
            End If
        Next item
        End If
        Next
        If toCopy = True Then
            Sheets(sheetIndex).Name = UCase(findWhat) + "+" + LCase(inclusion)
            Rows(item).Copy Destination:=Sheets(sheetIndex).Rows(j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        toCopy = False
    Next item
    sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1
    Continue = MsgBox(((j - 1) & " results were copied, do you have more keywords to enter?"), vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
Loop
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And where does it throw the error? I believe your code hasn't been pasted properly around the middle, by the way. You have a Next and End If on the same line.

Comment: Yeah it didn't paste properly. I updated showing one of the errors, but I am getting multiple. I went ahead and retried pasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `inclusion` is declared as a `String` variable, and contains a `String`, albeit a `String` separated by commas.  The `Ubound` function works on arrays.

To fix: Convert the string into an array using the `Split` function. See the below example for some quick help, and let us know if you need more details.

```
Sub Tests()
    Dim inclusion() As String

    inclusion = Split("One, Two, Three", ",")

    MsgBox (UBound(inclusion))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help, my program is now throwing the error "Compile error - For Each control vaiable on arrays must be Variant"

Comment: @wesree I'd say part of the problem may lie in the fact that you're using `item` variable in two separate instances within nested loops. You use `For item = 1...` and also `For Each item in Inclusion...`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last comment.

A variable in For Each must be of type Object or Variant.

To change your 'item' in a Variant, replace 'Dim item As Long' by 'Dim item As Variant', or even by 'Dim item' as a variable declared without a type is a Variant.